# Is it possible to set different duration/delay for transform options?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I want to set several transform options for my html object but with different duration and delay.

If i try to use something like that:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform, opacity;
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) scale(2); 
-webkit-transition-duration: 2000ms, 6000ms; 
-webkit-transition-delay: 0ms, 6000ms;
```

Then i will have different time function for transform and opacity but can i set different options for rotate and scale, e.g. rotate for 10s and scale 20s?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably not directly, but the same effect can be achieved by [nesting elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-2d-transforms-20090320/#transform-values).

Comment: Yes, that's should be possible though definitely harder than i thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Yes you can do this directly with CSS3 animations. If you have an opacity transform from 0 to 1 that lasts 20 seconds, and a 90 degree rotation that lasts 10 seconds, then you create a keyframe at 10 seconds with opacity .5 and rotation 90 degrees and another keyframe at 20 seconds with opacity 1 and rotation 90 degrees. It's sort of a pain, but it will work. Nesting divs is a bit cleaner (as Doug says above)

Ok here's the code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes foo {
 0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    opacity: 0;
 }
 50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    opacity: 0.5;
 }

 100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(90deg);
    opacity: 1;
 }
```

And you'd put

```
-webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
```

into your HTML.

Comment: I am sorry i didn't quite get it. Opacity (or any other 'normal' property) and webtransform timing could be set like this: -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform, opacity;
-webkit-transition-duration: 2000ms, 6000ms; But how in your example add timing for another webtransform - scale in my case (if webtransform is defined like: -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) scale(2); ). Thanks!

Comment: Edited the code -- I'm suggesting using animations not transitions

Comment: Unfortunately, this falls apart if you're specifying timing functions and you want the animation smooth across keyframes. It's 2015 now, is there a better answer yet?

Comment: Easing functions are fully specified - you just have to do some math (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-easing-1/)

Answer (score 0):

That would be problem to do it like Doug said if you have 3d perspective in your animation. Probably you could use "transform-style: preserve-3d" but it doesn't work in IE 10-11 and works weird in all other browsers exept Firefox. So the only solution i think is to use CSS3 animations. In your case it would be:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate_scale {

    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0);
     }
     50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0);
     }
     100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) scale(2);
     }
}
@keyframes rotate_scale {

    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0);
     }
     50% {
        transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0);
     }
     100% {
        transform: rotate(180deg) scale(2);
     }
}
```

So you can set the longest duration of your transforms. For example 20 seconds for rotation: `animation-duration: 20s;  animation-name: rotate_scale; -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;  -webkit-animation-name: rotate_scale;` And then just calculate when your another transform will begin. In the examle scale begins in ten seconds after rotation. So it would be a half of full time ( 50% ). And it would last 10 seconds so till the end of full time ( 100% ). But if you'd like to make scale duration 5 seconds for example you'd need to add new keyframe `75% { transform: rotate(135deg) scale(2); }` and write there **two** transforms.