# JQuery wait until ToggleClass function completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css

I am using ToggleClass to trigger an animation from css and need to call a function after the animation has ended.
I'm calling a function from the [typed.js](http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/) library.

```
 $('.anim').toggleClass('slide-down');
      $(".sentence").typed({
        strings: ["first sentence", "Second sentence." ],
        typeSpeed: 45,
        backDelay: 500,
        callback: function(){}
});
```

how can I make the typed function wait till the toggleClass has finished?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to wait for css transition to finish before applying next class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592933/how-to-wait-for-css-transition-to-finish-before-applying-next-class)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wait for the [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/animationend) event

```
$('.anim').toggleClass('slide-down').one('animationend', function () {
    $(".sentence").typed({
        strings: ["first sentence", "Second sentence."],
        typeSpeed: 45,
        backDelay: 500,
        callback: function () {}
    });
});
```

Or if you are using transition, then use [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/transitionend)

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fL86g/)

Comment: it's actually a transition, How can I use transitionend?

Comment: @Farzan replace `animationend` with `transitionend`